# set environment variable with specific HTTP header in htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, environment-variables

I'm trying to set an Environment variable if I got a specific HTTP Header sent.

So I tried a few different way that I will detail

```
Header set MY_HTTP_HEADER "1"

# tests with with SetEnvIf
SetEnvIf %{HTTP:MY_HTTP_HEADER} ^1$ THE_ENV=ok
SetEnvIf MY_HTTP_HEADER ^1$ THE_ENV=ok
SetEnvIf %{MY_HTTP_HEADER} ^1$ THE_ENV=ok

# tests with RewriteRule
RewriteCond %{HTTP:MY_HTTP_HEADER} ^1$
RewriteRule .* index.php [L,E=THE_ENV:ok]

RewriteCond MY_HTTP_HEADER ^1$
RewriteRule .* index.php [L,E=THE_ENV:ok]
```

There is something that I certainly missed, because all the codes above doesn't work.

**EDIT**
The correct one is `SetEnvIf MY_HTTP_HEADER ^1$ THE_ENV=ok` and like @anubhava pointed it doesn't work if you set the header in the same .htaccess so I created another page calling the actual page with CURL with this header `curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,array('MY_HTTP_HEADER: 1'));`

Comment: So which variable is not being set from above code?

Comment: I put all of them but I was testing it 1 by 1 of course and deactivating the others.

Comment: How are you sending `MY_HTTP_HEADER` header in the request?

Comment: I don't really understand what you mean by that... I set it in the .htaccess on the first line, am I doing it wrong?

Comment: Yes, see my answer for details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're making 2 mistakes:

1) This directive:

```
Header set MY_HTTP_HEADER "1"
```

Actually sends response header not request header. Use it like this to set request header:

```
RequestHeader set X-MY-HTTP-HEADER "1"
```

2) You're setting request header and checking for it in the same .htaccess. Try sending header in web request from browser (using some Rest client addon) and then you will find `THE_ENV=ok` env value in your index.php

Comment: Thank you for your reply, just a question is Header and Env the same thing? Because in PHP if I print all SERVER information and I do `SetEnv TEST_OK 123` and `RequestHeader set TEST_OK "456"` they both appear but the first with TEST_OK and the other one HTTP_TEST_OK... Ok I will try to understand a bit more thanks.

Comment: `env` is in the context of a server request. `headers` are part of HTTP request and response that travel between client and server.